# filter params for import users from AD

Tags: ldap

I'm to import users used this filter:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=PERSON))
```

And i want to add **RealName** parameter as filter.
RealName should contain 3 any words.
For example RealName contained "name middle_name surname" - it's good, need to import.
If RealName contained "name surname" (only two word) - wrong, not imported.

Can you help me with with filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LDAP queries can only use attributes that exist in Active Directory, and there is no attribute called "RealName".

You will have to split the input string yourself. So, for example, if you were given the string `"Necro The Human"`, you would have to split that into 3 strings using whatever programming language you're using.

Then you will have to insert those into an LDAP query that matches the three name attributes: `givenName`, `initials`, and `sn` (surname)

Your finished query would look something like this:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(givenName=Necro)(initials=The)(sn=Human))
```

Check if you're using `initials` or the `middleName` attribute for the middle name. It's the `initials` attribute that is labelled as "Initials" in Active Directory Users and Computers, so that may be what's used, even though [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-initials) says it's just for the initials of the full name, or middle initials (not the full middle name). It's also limited to only 6 characters, so you may be using `middleName` if you're storing full middle names.

If your company has the standard of setting the `displayName` to the user's full name, including middle name, then you could just match against that. But I think it would be pretty rare that the middle name would be in the display name.

```
(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(displayName=Necro The Human))
```

There is also [ambiguous name resolution](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22653.active-directory-ambiguous-name-resolution.aspx), but it searches other attributes (not just the first/last name) and it does not include `initials` or `middleName`. I mention it only because it's not well known and you may find some other use for it one day.

Comment: I take *RealName* param from Directory Utility on Mac Os. And this param not worked in my filter. thanks for answering. I will try your info.